# Why does this ggridges plot implies negative values when there are none?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

data(iris)
```

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Species))+ 
  ggridges::geom_density_ridges()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0, 4))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

This ggridges visualization implies that some petal widths for setosa and the others are below zero, but this shouldn't be possible since there are no negative values in the dataset. I am wondering why the visualization shows negative values being in the data at some frequency?

Comment: That's how kernel density estimates work. A little normal distribution is put at each x value, and these are all added up. If some of the x values are close to zero, then the tails of the normal density distributions will be non-zero for negative numbers. This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: To add to AllanCameron's comment, when density plots are generated, they tend to be "smooth" on the tails. This means that even if the data completely stops at `0`, there is a positive `y` just to the right of `x>0`, so between `x=0` and `x>0` there must be a contiguous and smooth curve, not an angle, elbow, or abrupt change in direction. You should not see ratcheting, angular, triangular, etc shapes in a density curve. The available options (in general, not available programmatically) are to under-rep-represent `y` values near `x=0` and make sure that `y=0` there, but that's also a bias.

Comment: Ty for the answers, I was unfamiliar with kernel density estimates.